# Tabindex is not focusing on the next element

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, accessibility

I'm trying to tab between different radio button inputs using React/TypeScript. I can get the first radio button focused, but when I click tab, it focuses outside of the radio buttons. I tried using react-focus-trap but tab wouldn't focus on any input elements (I may have been using it incorrectly though).

Here is my component where I am setting the tab index on the components

RadioButton.tsx

```
import { useState } from "react";
import type { SurveyAnswer } from "./demographicssurvey";

interface RadioButtonAnswersProps {
  answers: SurveyAnswer[];
  updateCurrentAnswer: (val: string) => void;
  setDisabled: (val: boolean) => void;
}
export default function RadioButtonAnswers({
  answers,
  updateCurrentAnswer,
  setDisabled,
}: RadioButtonAnswersProps) {
  const [disabledInput, setDisabledInput] = useState("");
  const handleChange = (val: string) => {
    updateCurrentAnswer(val);
    setDisabled(false);
  };

  const radioBtn = (a: SurveyAnswer, index: number) => {
    console.log("Index is:", index)
    return (
        <label>
          <input
            autoFocus={index === 0}
            tabIndex={0}
            className="form-radio"
            type="radio"
            name="myRadio"
            value={a.answer}
            onFocus={(e) =>  {
              e.target.checked = true;
              handleChange((e.target as HTMLInputElement).value)
            }}
            onClick={(e) => handleChange((e.target as HTMLInputElement).value)}
            onChange={() => {
              setDisabledInput("");
              return;
            }}
          />
          <span className="mx-2">{a.answer}</span>
        </label>
    );
  };

  const radioBtnText = (a: SurveyAnswer, index: number) => {
    return (
        <label>
          <input
            autoFocus={index === 0}
            tabIndex={0}
            type="radio"
            className="form-radio"
            name="myRadio"
            value={a.answer}
            onFocus={(e) =>  {
              e.target.checked = true;
              handleChange((e.target as HTMLInputElement).value)
            }}
            onClick={() => setDisabledInput(a.answer)}
            onChange={() => {
              return;
            }}
          />
          <span className="mx-2">
            {a.answer}
            <input
              className="form-input rounded"
              tabIndex={0}
              type={"text"}
              disabled={disabledInput !== a.answer}
              onChange={(e) =>
                handleChange(a.answer + (e.target as HTMLInputElement).value)
              }
            ></input>
          </span>
        </label>
    );
  };
  return (
      <>
        {answers.map((a, index) => {
          return (
            <ul key={index}>
              {a.answerType === "option"
                ? radioBtn(a, index)
                : a.answerType === "optionText"
                ? radioBtnText(a, index)
                : null}
            </ul>
          );
        })}
      </>
  );
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigating [Radio buttons](https://www.w3.org/wiki/RadioButton) is like navigating a select:

- focus with tab
- select an option with arrows

If you want to navigate your radio group by pressing tab, you will need to build your own radio buttons

Comment: Navigating with arrows does seem to work!

Answer (score 1):

Focusing the currently selected radio button with tab, and selecting other radio buttons of the same group with arrow keys and not tab, is just the normal way of working for radio buttons.

You'd better try not to change that behavior. Keyboard users are used to it working that way.
By doing in another way, the user may not understand how it works, and give up.

Additionally, by trying to make it working exactly the way you want, you may unintentionally prevent some users from using your site totally.

This is the principle of least surprise, it shouldn't be taken too lightly.

Playing with tabindex must be done with great care:

- Value 0 is to be used when you want to make something focusable while it is normally not
- Value -1 is to be used when you want something to be not focusable while it normally is
- Any value other than 0 or -1 completely breaks tab navigation sooner or later, so should never be used
- Adding tabindex=0 to an already naturally focusable element has in theory no effect, but is being responsible of weird bugs in the past and probably still now; so should be avoided